# Multi-Fermion interactions induced by integrating-out Yukawa-Higgs terms?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, fermions, higgs

Suppose one considers a **multi-component free fermions field theory** with field $\psi_{q_i}$ with a give global symmetry (such as U(1)). We can say that every component of fermions carry some U(1) charge $q_i$. Now, let us introduce Yukawa-Higgs term to mediate fermion-fermion interactions. Explicit Higgs charge are assigned to maintain the U(1) symmetry in Yukawa-Higgs term. We also consider the Higgs field strongly-disordered so do NOT break global symmetry (here U(1)) via the normal Higgs mechanism. This can be done by adding kinetic terms to Higgs field, and in principle $\langle \Phi \rangle=0$ but $ (\Phi-\langle \Phi \rangle)^2\neq0$, i.e. the Higgs field does not condense, but Higgs field strongly fluctuates.

> Here is the **Question**:
>
> whether **including all symmetry-allowed Yukawa-Higgs term of a single Higgs field ($\Phi$)** can induce **any symmetry-allowed multi-fermion interactions**?

I can imagine this may be true if we have:

> including **all symmetry-allowed Yukawa-Higgs term of (multi-component and multi-species) Higgs fields  ($\Phi_1$,$\Phi_2$,$\Phi_3$,$\Phi_4$,$\dots$)**
>
> $\Leftrightarrow$ (iff: correct?)
>
> induces **all symmetry-allowed multi-fermion interactions**.

But let us say if we have only **ONE single component scalar Higgs field**, say all symmetry-allowed Yukawa-Higgs term of $\psi_{q_i}^{n_i} \Phi^{m} \psi_{q_j}^{n_j}$ (with $\psi$ are fermions field and $\Phi$ is the only Higgs, with some power ${n_i},{n_j},m$ perhaps with complex conjugate $(\psi_{q_i}^{\dagger})^{|n_i|}$ if ${n_i}<0$.)  can one **prove or disprove** this is true or no that it can generate all multi-fermion interactions, such as $$V_{interaction}=\big( ({\psi}_{q_1} \nabla^1_x {\psi}_{q_1} \nabla^2_x {\psi}_{q_1} \dots \nabla^{N_{q_1}}_x {\psi}_{q_1}) \dots ({\psi}_{q_n} \nabla^1_x {\psi}_{q_n} \nabla^2_x {\psi}_{q_n} \dots \nabla^{N_{q_n}}_x {\psi}_{q_n}) \dots ) \big) + \text{hermitian conjugate}$$ with potential higher derivative terms?

Answer (score 4):

All terms that do not break explicitly the U(1) symmetry will be generated under the RG (in a Wilsonian approach). To see that, integrate out the scalar field. Then you have a theory with a four-fermions interaction. This interaction by itself will generate all possible interaction terms (with arbitrary number of fermionic fields and derivative terms).
The same thing arises in the case of a $\phi^4$ theory.

Comment: Thanks Adam! are you sure just one single Higgs scalar field is enough? Plus, your argument contains a loop-hole: it is not necessarily 4-fermion interactions. To maintain the U(1) symmetry, depending on each species fermion charge, it can have general n-fermion interactions (to maintain the U(1) unbroken).

Comment: Usually, a Yukawa coupling is a the form $\phi \bar\psi\psi$, so that will generate a 4 fermions coupling (between all the species) when integrated out.